# How to cast a column into decimal of varying significant digits in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have a column that is stored in ###0.0000000000 format. In a report I'm generating I need it to only show a few significant digits. Problem is the number needed changes based on the product with a default of 2. There's a column in another table that provides the required digits per each product.

I've tried a few things so far but it seems to not like it and throws a syntax error.

```
Cast(A.Price as Numeric(10,coalesce(B.Sig_Digits,2)))
```

That threw an error so I tried making the coalesce part a column and aliasing it in case the coalesce broke it, and that didn't work either. Round will take a column as an argument but I don't want it to round. Other than an ugly

```
case when Sig_digits = 1 then to_char(price,'###0.0') when Sig_digits = 2...
```

etc. what other options are there? This is a very large report, with 100+ columns and a few million rows so I'd prefer to not do the case when.

Comment: Please update your question to provide sample input data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TO_CHAR` with `RPAD` to add `0`s to the end of the format model to the correct number of decimal places:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/485fe/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value, sig ) AS
  SELECT 123.456789, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 123456789.123456789, 7 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( value, RPAD( 'FM999999999990.', sig + 15, '0' ) )
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/485fe/3/0)**:

```
| TO_CHAR(VALUE,RPAD('FM999999999990.',SIG+15,'0')) |
|---------------------------------------------------|
|                                            123.46 |
|                                 123456789.1234568 |
```